# size of data frames inside a dict

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

Imagine I have a dict which has 8 data frames inside (with different names)
Each data frame corresponds to a specific year. It has for example patients to a clinic for the years 2015,2016,2017 etc. Each data frame has a different number of rows (patients) but the same number of columns (tests they did for example) So my dict is of the following form

```
Years      Type           Size                  Value
2015       DataFrame      (4,99)           (here it has the column names)
2016       DataFrame      (125,99)
2017       DataFrame      (85,99)
2018       DataFrame      (250,99)
and so on
```

How can I access the size of those data frames? Because I cannot use for example df.size since the data frames have a different name.

```
# I create a list to save the number of entries per data frame
years = [] 

#j is a number for which after that number I want to calculate how many elements each data frame has
for i in range(j,number_of_years):
   p1 = df.size
   years.append(pl)
```

But as I said df.size does not work.

EDIT: To begin with, I read an excel file with multiple sheets. I use

```
#k is a string variable with the name of the excel file
file = pd.read_excel(k, sheet_name=None)

#Then I create the data frame from the dict. Basically it is a big data frame that combines all the data from my dict
df = pd.concat(file[frame] for frame in file.keys()).reset_index(drop=True)
```

So each data frame is a different year (2015,2016,2017 etc) and I want to create a new column called year that writes from which year that row is. Because each data frame has a different number of rows I thought of the process I mentioned before. My final outcome should be something like this

```
Years
2015
2015
2015
...
2016
2016
...
etc
```

So far I have transformed my dict from 8 data frames to 1 big data frame that combines all the patients. For example, the first 200 rows correspond to the patients from 2015. The next 330 from 2016. The next 100 from 2017 etc. I want to add a column to that big data frame where I write from which year the patient is. I cannot do it by hand(in a sense up to row 250 is 2015 etc) because if I read another excel file then the number of patients will be different

Comment: can you be more specific what doesn't work? are you getting wrong output or any error, etc..?

Comment: Hey. I do now know how to call basically the data frame inside the dict so i can ask the size of it. Because every data frame has a different name I cannot do it manually. I want to create a loop basically that loops through my dict gets the number of rows in each data frame and insert it in a list, which later i will use. Wait i ll update the question so you understand the purpose of what I am doing because perhaps there is an easier way to do it which I do not know

Comment: it's still not clear and one morething dataframe object doesn't have `keys()` method but you are using how `file.keys()`?

Comment: That command command I found on this website I think or on a video on Youtube on how to create a dataframe from a dict. Because I tried df =  pd.DataFrame.from_dict(file) and I was getting an error "  If using all scalar values, you must pass an index " But with this method it transforms my dict to a huge data frame that contains all the data from each data frame of the dict. I edited more information perhaps it is more understandable now

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like

```py
years = []
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5]])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [2,3,4], [3,4,5], [4,5,6]])
my_dict = {'df1':df1, 'df2':df2, 'df3':df3}

for df in my_dict:
    years += [my_dict[df].size]
```

And to access the last 5 dataframe size you can just write `years[len(years)-5:]`

Comment: Hey @meowulf thank you for posting. The issue is that I am not creating the dict. I just read an excel file and I cannot name them by hand since I cannot know beforehand how many dataframes each dict from the excel file will have

Comment: @Alex - The (unknown) dict / df key names do not matter, as you’re iterating the keys, therefore dynamic, as meowulf shows in the last line.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it. I just changed it to years += [len(file[d].index)]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! It turns out it is as meowulf suggested just change at the end to years += [len(file[df].index)]